# CSS Select element, how to disappear the arrow?

Tags: html, css

I want a nice style for a select element on my page.
So I've created a css:

```
.selectWebDropDown
{
   background-color:Transparent;
   background: url(../Images/ddl_Normal.png) no-repeat right #FFFFFF !important;   
   border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
   padding:4px; 
   line-height: 21px;

}

.selectWebDropDown:hover
{
  background-color:Transparent; 
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #FFFFFF url(../Images/ddl_Hover.png) no-repeat 0 0 !important; 
  padding:4px; 
  line-height: 21px;
}

.selectWebDropDown:active
{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:Transparent; 
  background: url(../Images/ddl_Pressed.png) no-repeat 0 0 !important; 
  padding:4px; 
  line-height: 21px;
}
```

The style is ok, the problem is that the arrow of the select doesn't dissapear... Is there a way to do this without using javascript... only css

Comment: Have you tried adding a :visited style that has the normal.png image as the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<select>` elements are notoriously difficult to style, especially if you want cross-browser consistency. Unfortunately, I'd go the JavaScript route and make drop-down replacements using lists.

Try a jQuery plugin such as [this](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) or [this](http://www.adamcoulombe.info/lab/jquery/select-box/).

Comment: You can write your own, or use a jQuery plugin such as [this](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) or [this](http://www.adamcoulombe.info/lab/jquery/select-box/).

Comment: Your answer works fine... can you put it as answer to mark it?